# Matplotlib - When I format ticks, they are not replaced and instead added to the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

Hello I am using Matplotlib to plot some curves for machine learning. I have the problem that when I format my x_ticks , instead of replacing the old ones they are added to the plot. See the first plot on the image below on the left where percent and numbers are plotted:

[image]

This is the code from scikit learn. I use `axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=5))` to format the first plot which seems to work, but like I said the labels are just added on top. I had the same problem with other matplotlib implementations in geopandas for example so I thought maybe someone knows what to do.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(10, 15))

plot_learning_curve(...)


def plot_learning_curve(
    estimator,
    title,
    X,
    y,
    axes=None,
    ylim=None,
    cv=None,
    n_jobs=None,
    train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5),
):
    """
    Generate 3 plots: the test and training learning curve, the training
    samples vs fit times curve, the fit times vs score curve.

    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : estimator instance
        An estimator instance implementing `fit` and `predict` methods which
        will be cloned for each validation.

    title : str
        Title for the chart.

    X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Training vector, where ``n_samples`` is the number of samples and
        ``n_features`` is the number of features.

    y : array-like of shape (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_features)
        Target relative to ``X`` for classification or regression;
        None for unsupervised learning.

    axes : array-like of shape (3,), default=None
        Axes to use for plotting the curves.

    ylim : tuple of shape (2,), default=None
        Defines minimum and maximum y-values plotted, e.g. (ymin, ymax).

    cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None
        Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
        Possible inputs for cv are:

          - None, to use the default 5-fold cross-validation,
          - integer, to specify the number of folds.
          - :term:`CV splitter`,
          - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

        For integer/None inputs, if ``y`` is binary or multiclass,
        :class:`StratifiedKFold` used. If the estimator is not a classifier
        or if ``y`` is neither binary nor multiclass, :class:`KFold` is used.

        Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
        cross-validators that can be used here.

    n_jobs : int or None, default=None
        Number of jobs to run in parallel.
        ``None`` means 1 unless in a :obj:`joblib.parallel_backend` context.
        ``-1`` means using all processors. See :term:`Glossary <n_jobs>`
        for more details.

    train_sizes : array-like of shape (n_ticks,)
        Relative or absolute numbers of training examples that will be used to
        generate the learning curve. If the ``dtype`` is float, it is regarded
        as a fraction of the maximum size of the training set (that is
        determined by the selected validation method), i.e. it has to be within
        (0, 1]. Otherwise it is interpreted as absolute sizes of the training
        sets. Note that for classification the number of samples usually have
        to be big enough to contain at least one sample from each class.
        (default: np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5))
    """
    if axes is None:
        _, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 5))

    axes[0].set_title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        axes[0].set_ylim(*ylim)
    axes[0].set_xlabel("Training examples")
    axes[0].set_ylabel("Score")

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _ = learning_curve(
        estimator,
        X,
        y,
        cv=cv,
        n_jobs=n_jobs,
        train_sizes=train_sizes,
        return_times=True,
    )
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    fit_times_mean = np.mean(fit_times, axis=1)
    fit_times_std = np.std(fit_times, axis=1)

    # Plot learning curve
    axes[0].grid()
    axes[0].fill_between(
        train_sizes,
        train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
        train_scores_mean + train_scores_std,
        alpha=0.1,
        color="r",
    )
    axes[0].fill_between(
        train_sizes,
        test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
        test_scores_mean + test_scores_std,
        alpha=0.1,
        color="g",
    )
    axes[0].plot(
        train_sizes, train_scores_mean, "o-", color="r", label="Training score"
    )
    axes[0].plot(
        train_sizes, test_scores_mean, "o-", color="g", label="Cross-validation score"
    )
    axes[0].legend(loc="best")
    axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=5))
    
    # Plot n_samples vs fit_times
    axes[1].grid()
    axes[1].plot(train_sizes, fit_times_mean, "o-")
    axes[1].fill_between(
        train_sizes,
        fit_times_mean - fit_times_std,
        fit_times_mean + fit_times_std,
        alpha=0.1,
    )
    axes[1].set_xlabel("Training examples")
    axes[1].set_ylabel("fit_times")
    axes[1].set_title("Scalability of the model")

    # Plot fit_time vs score
    fit_time_argsort = fit_times_mean.argsort()
    fit_time_sorted = fit_times_mean[fit_time_argsort]
    test_scores_mean_sorted = test_scores_mean[fit_time_argsort]
    test_scores_std_sorted = test_scores_std[fit_time_argsort]
    axes[2].grid()
    axes[2].plot(fit_time_sorted, test_scores_mean_sorted, "o-")
    axes[2].fill_between(
        fit_time_sorted,
        test_scores_mean_sorted - test_scores_std_sorted,
        test_scores_mean_sorted + test_scores_std_sorted,
        alpha=0.1,
    )
    axes[2].set_xlabel("fit_times")
    axes[2].set_ylabel("Score")
    axes[2].set_title("Performance of the model")

    return plt
```

Comment: Your first plot looks right: a value of `4000` in percent is `400000 %`.

Comment: Is your intention to have the plot as a percentage of the last `fit_time`, such that `100 %` means the maximum `fit_time`?

Comment: Oh I see sorry, is there a way for format the samples so that they have values in the thousand for example 4k instead of 4000, or 4x10^3?

Comment: I added an answer to the question in the comment. Could you update your question such that it is clear that you are asking how to display the values in the thousands (as you asked in the comment above)?

Answer (score 0):

One method to reduce the number of zeros is to display in "scientific" notation. You can set your formatter to:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

...

axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:.0e}'))
```

This will display labels as (apologies for the ASCII art):

```
  |      |      | 
4e+04  5e+04  6e+04
```